# ¿Cómo mostrar mis coordenas de un módulo gps conectado a Raspberry pi en un link de google maps?

Tags: python, google-maps, raspberry-pi, gps

[Mostrar la ubicación de un modulo gps en un link de 
google maps en python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAypB.png)

Buenas a todos!!! Aquí muestro un código en python que quiero modificar para enviar una alerta a través de sms en donde se muestre que tuvo un accidente y el enlace de google maps con la ubicación de gps en tiempo real por mi modulo gps configurado con puerto serial, en el código se logra mandar por sms el mensaje de "tuvo una caída" y el link de google maps pero sin las coordenadas. (Mi código esta pensado para que se pruebe en cualquier lugar por lo que debe de tomar cualquier coordenada dependiendo la ubicación en donde el modulo GPS capte la caída, no la misma ubicación estática). *Cabe mencionar que por separado ambos códigos funcionan bien, el de GSM manda el mensaje(como se muestra) y el de GPS  por separado si muestra las coordenadas en tiempo real(latitud y longitud) pero cuando los junto y quiero enviar el mensaje con la ubicación me salen las siguientes salidas al ejecutar el código* Por favor ayuda, soy principiante en python y raspberry.

[image: salida parte1]
[image: salida parte2]
[image: sms en cel]

```
`#!/usr/bin/python
import webbrowser
import serial, time, pynmea2

#Enable Serial Communication
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
#Transmitting AT Commands to the Modem

#ser.flushOutput()
#ser.flushInput()

ser.write('ATE'+'\r') #Check to see if modem is responding
str = ser.readline()
print str
time.sleep(1)

ser.write('AT+CGPSOUT=32'+'\r') #Outputs raw NMEA data
str = ser.readline()
print str
time.sleep(3)

ser.write('AT+CGNSPWR=1'+'AT+CGPSSTATUS=?'+'\r') #Turns on the 
GPS power
str = ser.readline()
print str
time.sleep(3)

while str.find ("Location Not Fix") > 1:
      print 'Waiting for a fix - ',str
      ser.flushInput()
      ser.flushOutput()
      time.sleep(15)
      str = ser.readline(100)

ser.write('AT+CGNSTST=1'+'\r') #Starts sending data to UART
str = ser.readline() 
print str
#time.sleep(5)

#Parsing Raw NMEA data through pynmea2
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

def parseGPS(str):

    if str.find("GGA") > 0:
       data = pynmea2.parse(str)
       print "Timestamp: %s -- Lat: %s %s -- Lon: %s %s:" % 
       (data.timestamp, data.latitude, data.lat_dir, data.longitude, 
         data.lon_dir)


url = ('https://maps.google.com/maps?q='  + 'lat' + '+' + 'lng')

# Enable Serial Communication
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

# Transmitting AT Commands to the Modem
# '\r\n' indicates the Enter key
port.write('AT'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv
time.sleep(.1)

port.write('ATE0'+'\r\n')      # Disable the Echo
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv
time.sleep(.1)

port.write('AT+CMGF=1'+'\r\n')  # Select Message format as Text mode
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv
time.sleep(.1)

port.write('AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0'+'\r\n')   # New SMS Message Indications
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv
time.sleep(.1)

# Sending a message to a particular Number
port.write('AT+CMGS="55xxxxxxxx"'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv
time.sleep(.1)

port.write('Tuvo una caida!'+'\r\n')  # Message
port.write('click here to see this location in google maps!:<a href= "' + 
url + '">go</a>')
rcv = port.readline(10)
print rcv

port.write("\x1A") # Enable to send SMS
  for i in range(10):
  rcv = port.readline(10)
  print rcv

while True:
  str = ser.readline()
  parseGPS(str)`
```

Comment: El código no está bien indentado. Corrígelo para que te puedan ayudar mejor. El problema creo que está en la línea `url = ('https://maps.google.com/maps?q='  + 'lat' + '+' + 
'lng')` donde `lat` y `lon` los pasas como *string* y no como variable. Otra cosa, si es posible, usa Python3, el mantenimiento a Python 2 se acaba en poco más de un mes.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Tengo esa duda, como podría pasar lat y lng como variables? @kikocorreoso

Comment: Guarda los valores de la latitud y de la longitud en las variables `lat` y `lng`, respectivamente, y cambia esta línea `url = ('https://maps.google.com/maps?q='  + 'lat' + '+' + 'lng')` por esta `url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='  + str(lat) + '+' + str(lng)`

Comment: @kikocorreoso y sabes como puedo guardar los valores de la latitud y longitud? pense que se guardaban en la linea que dice data.latitude y data.lat_dir

Comment: En esa línea no guardas nada, solo lo muestras en pantalla. Para guardar una variable debes hacer, por ejemplo, `lat = data.latitude`. Pero lo debes hacer de tal forma que sea luego accesible desde donde quieras darle uso. Te recomiendo que hagas una nueva pregunta con tu nueva duda y dejes un ejemplo mínimo reproducible de lo que quieres hacer.